# How can I read a file via a jQuery AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json

Site is on Linux and current web server is on location

```
 /var/www/
```

i have some one html file on location

```
 /var/www/setpOne/index.html
```

now if I set path in ajax like this ("/csv") it will find csv inside
    /var/www/setpOne/ 
right ?

so and if i add ./  before it will go outside ot current package
so that way ia m trying to read on the location where csv is placed

in side that code I am wanted to get csv file from ajax 
D#.js is lib that i simply use for so

```
        $.get("here is location of .csv file",  function(error, json) {
                if(json) {
                    isPort = true;
                    loadDataToPan(json);
                }
           });
```

Now my file os on location

```
/home/roman001/csv/test.csv
```

So how can i call this part from current aajx code

Comment: Are you trying to open a local file in your web page?

Comment: Yes I am have parallel code that generate this file and need to read from web

Comment: So what's the URL of the file?

Comment: /home/roman001/csv/test.csv

Comment: That's not a URL... It would be in the form of http://localhost/path/to/file.csv

Comment: But my web server is inside /var/www/ so i think I have to come two package out and than read file ?

Comment: What webserver are you running?

Comment: if i just set /cav/test.csv/  it will fine inside current location like /var/www/siteone/csv

Comment: You can't do AJAX requests to file paths.

Comment: it's php  and this code is simple just for that confirmation of autogenerated files

Comment: ok any pther option for that ?

Comment: Any other option to do what? 'confirmation of autogenerated files' sorry, that's not in your question. File paths are not URLs. For me to be able to help I'm going to need to know what your server config is.

Comment: With an AJAX request to a URL, you're trying to make an AJAX request to a file path. Do you need help in understanding the difference?

Comment: When I add ./  it let me go out of the current location that why I wanted to reach on right location

Comment: Add './' to where? Edit your question, you're being really unclear. Explain how you've set your server up. What software stack you're using, etc.

Comment: You cant access local files from a webserver. They need to be served by something to be accessible. And as Rollo has said a file path isnt a url.

Comment: Your server is at `/var/www/`. It can access files within that because any files within that folder are being server by the server. Files outside this folder are not accessible from the server.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things wrong with the question but I'm going to go out on a limb and try and answer it.

> [How] do I read a file from outside of a webserver via json?

You can't, a file must be accessible over http/https for it to be accessed though an AJAX request.

If you put `test.csv` in `/var/www/test.csv`, I'd assume you'd be able to access it from `http://localhost/test.csv`.

```
$.get("http://localhost/test.csv",  function(data) { 
   // data will contain the string of your CSV file
});
```

As a further note, you don't access files though JSON. JSON is just a very popular web serialization format. You access external files in JavaScript via XMLHttpRequest, better known as AJAX.

Comment: OK forget ajax what if I am opening this file.directly and need to read file than no server comes ..

Comment: Can you fix the grammar and structuring of the comment? I understand that English may not be your first language, but I can't read what you said.

Comment: You can't 'forget' Ajax, if there's no server you can't read the file.